# Struts form serialize and post to servlet using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets, struts

I have a jsp page backed by a struts form bean.I need to send the form data to a servlet via ajax. I use the form.serialize while sending the form through ajax. But when the form data get in the servlet, I cannot do a request.getParameter on any of the form fields.

Here are the code snippets:

## JavaScript in JSP

```
function getValue()
{
    var frm = $('form[name="myForm"]');

    alert(frm.serialize())   ;  //shows all values as a nice query string as          action=Register&flow=false&fname=john&  .........

     $.post("myServlet", {data: frm.serialize()},function(response){
        alert(response);
    });

}
```

## Form in JSP

```
<html:form name="myForm"  method="post" action="/myAction.to" type="com.xyz.myForm">
.
.
.
<div class="buttonCenter">
<a href="javascript:getValue()"> 
Continue 
</a> 
</div>
.
.
.
</html:form>
```

## This is Servlet method

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {

         logger.info(req.getParameter("fname"));  //Shows null


    //some other code
    }
```

Is there anything that I am missing here?
I am really stuck at this and any feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use data.fname in request.getParameter()